# Buying a bicycle

Tags: road-bike, commuter, hybrid-bike, shopping

I'm looking for a bicycle to commute to work (<2 miles), do groceries (~2-3 miles), go to school (~8 miles). Would [this](http://www.bikesdirect.com/products/windsor/essex_sale.htm) be a good bike for that? (one of the cheapest bikes on bikesdirect.com)

Comment: One downside is that it's a single speed.  Depending on how hilly your area is you might want to opt for a bike with some gears. Especially if you are hauling groceries as well.

Comment: I can't see paying $200 for a cheap bike when you can pick up a better one for $50 at a yard sale or off of Craig's List or whatever.  And any bike you buy, new or used, you should ride first, to see how it fits you and just how it "feels".

Comment: [Here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/10138/1584) is a thread on test-riding a bike, and [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7089/1584) is one on checking out a used bike.

Comment: [Here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/743/1584) is another thread on buying a used bike.

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate question for this S.E. forum. From the FAQ: "only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: shopping recommendations are off topic anyway, as they are never in any way constructive and wont help future visitors.

Comment: Appreciate the comments. I'll keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the comments on your question are good, i'll answer anyway.

Short answer: Yes for your specific needs this is a fitting bike. 
Longer. Yes, If you have some hills, the 3 speed oxford model may help.

Buying a used bike off craigslist for someone with little bike knowledge is probably not a great idea. a $50 - 100 bike in my area is generally pretty old. beat up and not worth the savings.

Comment: Yup, looking back this isn't a very helpful question but thanks for the answer anyway.