# Which bicycle do you recommend for a short daily city commute that can last for a solid 8-10 years?

Tags: road-bike, product-rec

I need a road bike for my daily commute. I live in Philadelphia and am looking on Craigslist and found a couple options. Let me know what you guys think. Feel free to suggest anything else you find around my area as well!

http://pastebin.com/V2KxLzyK

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Any ideas on on the the first three I selected?

Comment: They're all overpriced.  The Nishiki is the only one besides the Lotus that would be worth considering, and is probably the newest of the lot.  That Huffy didn't cost that much new.

Comment: That Schwinn Traveler has a Biopace crankset-that's pretty neat. Also, these bikes are wildly different sizes! Figure out what fits and go from there.

Comment: I'm looking at a 21speed Nishiki Sport: http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3322740436.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any medium quality bike in good condition should hold up to 10 years of light commuting, with proper maintenance.  (But proper maintenance is key -- you need a new chain about every 2000 miles, new rear cluster about every 5000, new tires somewhere in there.  Chain needs to be cleaned and lubed occasionally, and everything adjusted about once a year.)

There are several threads here that cover buying a used bike, such as this one: [What can I do to be sure I'm getting a fair deal when buying a used bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7089/what-can-i-do-to-be-sure-im-getting-a-fair-deal-when-buying-a-used-bike/7096#7096)

(And be sure you read up on checking bike FIT.)

Comment: Is this a good deal?   http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3310937160.html

Comment: It looks nice in the picture.  Note that it's OLD -- lugged steel frame, 27" wheels, non-indexed shifters.  And note that it's sized for a fairly short person.  Maybe a little high priced, though Lotus was supposedly a premier brand at the time.  Might be a little difficult getting parts for it.  (If you're not into old bikes I'd recommend something a little newer, from an ease of service standpoint.)

Comment: How about this: http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3322740436.html

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @Sachin -- Like I said, it's overpriced (and ugly).  Nishiki isn't a premium brand but is generally decent quality.  (I notice you've picked a lot of different style bikes.  Probably you're better off buying a serviceable $25 bike at a garage sale and riding it a bit to learn what style you'd really like.)

Answer (score 1):

I commute 13 miles each way on a mix of road and paved trails (poorly maintained), I started off using my old mountain bike but wanted something more road friendly.  After a lot of forum blog reading and asking on twitter I finally settled on a [Surly Cross Check](http://surlybikes.com/bikes/cross_check).  I've used it four days a week for the past five months and love it.  I swapped out the knobby tires for slicks and added a rack and fenders.

Comment: Is this a good deal?   http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3310937160.html

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment now and the posting is already deleted.

Comment: How about this: http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3322740436.html

Comment: looks like Nishiki bikes are going for $240 new on Google Shopping, not sure on this specific model.  I would hold out for something a little higher end.

Answer (score 1):

How long is your commute? If it is not very long, a road bike may not be the best choice. A mountain bike or a hybrid is cheaper.

What is the pavement like? If the roads are rough, a road bike will not be as comfortable or as stable.

The most important thing is bike fit. Try on the bike before buying it. If you want to use it for 10 years, you want it to be comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Any used ten speed that fits should work for a commuter.  Just examine the frame for cracks, and also for exposed rust or bubbles under the paint job.  I think you would benefit from a steel frame, both for longevity and smoothing out the potholes.  If its' longer than 10 miles or so one way a lighter weight bike might be a higher priority depending on your level of fitness.

Comment: Is this a good deal?   http://philadelphia.craigslist.org/bik/3310937160.html

Comment: examine crank arms for cracks too!  I broke one off soon after buying a used bike.  could have gone very badly for me.