# Is KCP a trustable bicycles Brand?

Tags: identify-this-bike, shopping, bso

I recently found a second-hand bike that looks interesting, but the brand is KCP, and even with a lot of search, I'm not able to find any result about it.

You can find below a picture and a link to the [KCP 26" Chicago](https://www.amazon.fr/KCP-CHICAGO-suspendu-Vitesses-anthracite/dp/B005FETWLO) mountain bike
[image]

What is "KCP"? Should I trust this supposed "brand"? Do you recommand me not to buy this and look into well-known or better known brands?

Comment: Consider that probably 80% of the bicycles sold in the US and western Europe are produced in maybe 5 factories in China.  Two identical bikes off the assembly line one behind the other might get slapped with different brand decals.

Comment: A quick Google for KCP bikes fetched up loads on Amazon and a retailer in Germany, they're cheap and cheerful, ride until it goes wrong, buy a better one and chalk it up to experience.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I wasn't aware of this fact this is interesting, have you any sources ? By following your reasonment getting a BSO is the same as getting a well-known brand isn't it?

Comment: The supposed five factories do produce a wide variety of bikes, this being low end. And if you go on actual alibaba, you'll see that there are more than five suppliers.

Comment: "any bike is better than walking"   but don't have high expectations for this bike.   Given its already second hand, could be quite near to the end of its life already.  Then again, cheap bikes are often bought with the best of intentions then Ridden Once Put Away.   You should weigh the options, and be prepared to save up for something better.

Comment: It is not kind to downvote me for a for a legitimate question as a beginner. Without even telling me the reason behind this downvote :l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the KCP bike is a so called 'Bicycle Shaped Object' (BSO).

BSO is a popular term for rather cheap bikes that are sold, for instance, via Amazon and supermarkets and often fail after short rides. Repairs are usually not feasible or economical. BSOs are targeted at the many riders who buy a bike to ride it once and then let it rust in a shed.

The answers to the question [BSO identification for amateurs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/32429/30402) will help you to find out if the present KCP bike is such a BSO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I didn't even knew the term BSO before, so in conclusion do you recommand me buying a true brand and avoid BSO ?

Comment: Avoid BSOs, they are hardly ever worth it. If you do not want to spend some 300 Eurodollarpounds, consider buying used, consider bike share/rental, or look for deals on quality bikes. For instance, here in Germany one may get a BSO for about 200 Euro, and a decent 3-speed city bike for about 330. A decent used bike starts at 150. While a new bike share start up rents out their bikes for 20 a month (one keeps the same bike, and swaps it if anything needs maintenance).

Comment: Especially avoid fancy looking BSO. Never get a full suspension bike unless you really pay a lot. The springs are bouncy and make it more of a risk going off road than using a decent unsuspended MTB. Those things ride more like [pogo sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_stick) than a dampening.

Answer (score 7):

To add to the other answer, the obvious signs here are:

- Unknown brand sold by Amazon
- Tourney, Zoom and unbranded components
- Mix of disc and rim brakes
- Unified rear triangle rear suspension
- Rear shock has huge coil spring and no visible damper

Smaller suspicious things are cable routing over the moving gap, rack and fender mounts, removable cantilever studs that are left in place, trouser protector disc etc

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in conclusion I should avoid to buy such a bike, am I right ?

Comment: Absolutely avoid. If you have to buy cheap, try to avoid suspension, gears or anything that adds complexity.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your feedback, I'll look to well-known brands and quality bikes in this case

Comment: @ojs Certainly avoid suspension but I'm not sure that avoiding gears is good advice. Tourney isn't terrible and a bike with gears is often a good deal more useful than one without.