# looking for an entry level bike

Tags: beginner

I need your help.  I am looking for an entry level bike to ride everyday.  I am looking for something to excercise.  I am 6 feet tall and weigh about 240lb.  I want to start slow about 10 miles a day around a park that is grass and cement or riding at the beach again on cement or blacktop.  Eventually I would like to get into longer rides.  Im looking for somehting max price of out the door $350-400(thats even pushing it, but I will if it is going to be worth it).  I do need to get myself in shape.  Any help and recommendations would be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Find a used bike.  If you have a cyclist buddy, have him help you pick out a good one, but likely you can find *something* for $50 or so, so even if your first try isn't the best, it's still a fair investment.  (Search here for some articles about how to evaluate a used bike.)

Comment: See this article: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9948/how-can-i-get-started-riding-without-spending-a-fortune-too-much

Comment: check out "hybrid" bikes

Comment: 10 miles a day is a lot for someone just starting out

Comment: Can't really help you beyond the other comments but wanted to wish you luck. 6 years ago I was 230lbs, I have been cycling since then and have been 160lbs for about the last 2 years. It will obviously take time but it can be done. Get in the saddle and watch your clothes get bigger! Oh, and I started off with just 2 miles, twice a day, Mon-Fri, and was seeing results. I knew it was time to do more when I got sad on Friday because I wouldn't ride again until Monday!

Comment: Second hand lets you try a bike and ride until you have some idea about what you want from a bike. Whatever bike you start with you're likely to decide you don't like after a year, so ideally start with cheap-but-works (ie, not a $99 "bicycle shaped object")

Comment: I also think 50 bucks is a bit low. 150-200 is probably closer to what you're going to pay for something decent on the used bike market. But an old rigid (i.e. no suspension) mountain bike (e.g. 80s Specialized Hardrock) with slicks will do nicely for this purpose.

Comment: @Batman - If you check Craig's List, garage sales, etc, you will find a number of bikes quite reasonably priced.  I just checked Craig's list for our area (county population 145K) and saw a couple of nice bikes at $50 and about ten below $150.  And keep in mind that many of those are "best offer" and can be talked down if you have cash in hand.

Comment: And, of course, one should always ask friends and neighbors if they know of a bike that's not being used.  There are millions of bikes sitting in the backs of garages, collecting dust.

Comment: @Daniel: I confess, I am guilty of having three of those millions.......

Comment: At 6 foot you have a chance of getting a dirt cheap new bike that almost fits, or a 2nd hand bike.  I ended up on a too-small new bike because I'm 6'4 and couldn't find anything 2nd hand.  It makes learning to ride much harder.

Comment: What does everyone think of the Forge Mstreet bike?  I know they are at Target, but it is cheaper then going for something at Performance bike shop.  The cheapest one I can get is over $400 at Performance Bikes.

Comment: Also if i go through craigslist what type of bike or brand should i look for or shearch for?

Comment: It helps if it's a recognizable brand, but you're unlikely to recognize many perfectly good brands.  One thing you can do is ask a cycling buddy to point out the things that identify a cheap bike, such as lots of plastic, crudely made "dropouts", one-piece cranks, steel stampings vs aluminum castings for handlebar mounts, etc.  In fact, make a couple of trips to Target and a couple to a good bike shop and study the differences in bikes.  Also, observe any congregation of bikes in a bike rack to pick out the better looking ones and see what you notice.

Answer (score 2):

Re- iterating comments- Second hand will offer best value for money. Avoid chain store bikes. Much better to get a use quality bike that is 1/2 worn out than a new cheap and nasty one. I suggest a Hybrid (or Comfort) bike with flat handle bars as a good starter. Road bikes are designed light to go fast at the expense of comfort (experienced riders are used to it). A Mountain bike is another alternate that will work, although not quite as well on paved surfaces.

Key things are to get the right sized bike. If at all possible get a cyclist mate to help out (ask around work if you don't know of anyone - I am sure someone will step up).

Visit a couple of bike shops, I recommend find ones with lots of kids bikes as they know about tight budgets and are used to dealing with inexperienced riders. They may have suitable used bikes, or last year model on big discount. Even if you do not plan to buy from them, you  may need them fro service, so they should be more than happy to talk about your needs and offer advice.

Don't spend all your money on the bike. You will need helmet, pump, spare tubes and puncture repair kit (learn how to use these). I strongly recommend padded bike shorts. If skin tight lycra is not your thing, you can get baggies (common with MTB'ers) and even ones that are underwear. Really good shorts are expensive, but even cheaper ones will make a difference to comfort when riding.

You don't say what your current fitness level is. Make sure you start out easy, even if you are super fit. Cycling uses different muscles to what you are used to going to hard to quickly usually ends badly. I would say 10 miles a day is too much for the first weeks, but is a good target.

Don't be talked into buying a bike for when you are fitter and training for the Tour de.... If you do you will upgrade it before then anyway, but do by a bike that is of reasonable quality.

Comment: I started writing an answer but this along the other comments should give the OP good guidance. I would emphasize the **take it slow** angle: 3 miles (5 km) *maximum* on alternate days for the first week, then *slowly* build up. Go on rides to explore the neighborhood, and get a bike lock so that you can ride to the shops etc, instead of always going training.

Comment: Loads of good advice in here Matt