# Which type of bicycle is best for weight loss?

Tags: product-rec, weight, fitness

I want to know which type of bicycle is best for weight loss.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.SX! In its current form your question might be closed as too broad or primarily opinion-based. Please have a look at our [help pages](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help) and take our [guided tour](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how good questions and answers should look like. Maybe you want to refine your question afterwards.

Comment: Don't let someone talk you into a bike you don't want, and don't let "glitter" attract you to a bike that you don't want (unless, of course glitter, literal or figurative, is something you like).  Find a bike that you will ride.  (I usually recommend a used/borrowed bike for folks starting out, until they figure out their "style".)

Comment: Even though this question is "closed", it has some good, detailed advice:  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20743/type-of-cycle-for-losing-weight-and-staying-fit-for-a-beginner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whichever type you will ride the most. If you like to go off road, get a mountain bike. If you plan to stay on the roads, then a road bike or hybrid will work well. Make sure the bike fits you well and is comfortable. Make sure it is a good quality bike that won't break after 1000 km. A bike that's sitting in your garage because you don't like it or because it was cheap and didn't last will not help you lose weight. Any type of biking combined with a proper diet will help you lose weight, provided you put in the miles.

Comment: Yeah, mainly the bike must fit you, must be comfortable, and must be easy for you to operate.