# What to look out for in a second hand bike buy

Tags: full-suspension, xc

I am looking into buying a second hand bicycle. What should one look out for (frame and component wise) when buying second hand, both for hardtail and full suspension xc/all mountain type bicycles?

Comment: First and foremost, learn how to tell a good quality bike from a department store bike.  (Not hard, but it takes a bit of homework.  Look particularly in the area of the front and rear dropouts on known good and "cheapie" bikes.)

Comment: Maybe some [useful information here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/743/what-should-i-look-for-when-buying-a-used-bicycle) but that deals more with road bikes. Also [more info here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16678/what-are-some-red-flags-to-look-for-when-buying-a-used-road-bike).